# What the NumPy array stores when I convert a grayscale image into a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I converted a 32 x 32 grayscale image into a NumPy array using this procedure

```
image = Image.open('bn2.bmp')
nparray=np.array(image)
```

when I print the NumPy array, it prints 6 different matrices. When I printed the size of the NumPy array, it showed me 3072. I suppose that the calculation is something like 3 x 32 x 32 . But I would like to know why, what is the NumPy array storing?

Comment: It would be easiest if you could share the specific file that you are reading.  I don't know what you mean when you say "it prints 6 different matrix".  If you can't share the file, at least show the values of `nparray.dtype` and `nparray.shape`.  The size 3072 is equal to 32*32*3, so I suspect that your file is actually a color file.   You say it is grayscale, so that probably means that in each color, the red, green and blue components are all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation on the page [A crash course on NumPy for images](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html)

If you use `shape`,

```
nparray.shape
```

this will give the dimensions of the image as something like

```
(32, 32, 3)
```

which gives the size you found (32 x 32 x 3 = 3072)

What this shows is that your image is a 32-by-32 pixel image with three channels (red, green, and blue). If it were grayscale, the size would be 32 x 32 = 1024, corresponding to a shape of:

`(32, 32)`

Incidentally, to convert your image to grayscale, you would need to use something like [`rgb2gray`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#rgb2gray) (link to documentation).